# react - rendering multiple components

Tags: reactjs

So I have two components... and I want them to render one after the other... THe code is below

```
 var Recipe = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {editing:false},
   {titles: []}
  },

  edit: function (){
    this.setState({editing:true});
  },


  remove: function(){
    this.props.deleteFromBoard(this.props.index)
  },
  save: function (){

    this.props.updateRecipeText(this.refs.newText.value,this.props.index)
        this.setState({editing:false});

  },


    renderNormal: function() {
    return (
      <div className="recipeContainer">
        <div>{this.props.children}</div>
        <button onClick ={this.edit} className ="button-primary">Edit</button>
        <button onClick ={this.remove} className ="button-remove">Remove</button>
</div>

    );
  },
  renderForm: function() {
    return (
      <div className="recipeContainer">
        <textArea ref="newText" defaultValue ={this.props.children}></textArea>
        <button onClick ={this.save} className ="button-danger">Save</button>
</div>

    );
  },






  render: function() {
    if(this.state.editing){
      return this.renderForm();
  }

    else{
      return this.renderNormal();
    }

  }
});

var RecipeTitle = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
    return {editingTitle:false}
  },
    edit: function (){
    this.setState({editingTitle:true});
  },



  remove: function(){
    this.props.deleteFromBoard(this.props.index)
  },
  save: function (){

   this.props.updateTitle(this.refs.newTextTitle.value,this.props.index)
        this.setState({editingTitle:false});

  },


  renderTitleNormal: function(){
    return(
          <div>   

    <h2>{this.props.children}</h2>
        <button onClick = {this.edit}>Edit</button> 
</div>
      )
  },
      renderTitleForm: function() {
    return (
      <div>   

                <textArea ref="newTextTitle" ></textArea>
        <button onClick ={this.save} className ="button-danger">Save</button>


</div>

    );
  },

    render: function() {

    if(this.state.editingTitle){
      return this.renderTitleForm();


  }  else{
return this.renderTitleNormal();  

  }
    }
});



var Board = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {

    return {
      recipes: [
      ],
   titles: [

   ]
    } 

  },
  add: function(text,title){
        var arr = this.state.recipes;
arr.push(text);
    this.setState({recipes: arr})
    var arrTitle = this.state.titles;
    arrTitle.push("Title");
    this.setState({titles: arrTitle})
  },


  removeRecipe: function (i) {
    var arr = this.state.recipes;
    console.log(arr);
    arr.splice(i,1);
    this.setState({recipes: arr})
  },
    removeTitle: function (i) {
    var arr = this.state.titles;
    arr.splice(i,1);
    this.setState({titles: arr})
  },
  updateRecipe: function (newText, i) {
    var arr = this.state.recipes;
    arr[i]=newText;
        this.setState({recipes: arr})

  },
eachTitle: function (title, i){
return (<div><RecipeTitle key={i} index={i} updateTitleText={this.updateTitle} >{title}</RecipeTitle></div>);                  
      },


  updateTitleText: function (newTitle, i) {
    var arr = this.state.titles;
    arr[i]=newTitle;
        this.setState({titles: arr})

  },

  eachRecipe:

 function (text, i){
return (<div><Recipe key={i} index={i}  updateRecipeText={this.updateRecipe} deleteFromBoard={this.removeRecipe}>{text}</Recipe></div>);                  
      },
  eachTitle:

 function (title, i){
return (<div><RecipeTitle key={i} index={i} updateTitle ={this.updateTitleText} deleteFromBoard={this.removeRecipe}>{title}</RecipeTitle></div>);                  
      },


   render: function () {
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.add.bind(null,'Default Text')}>Add New</button>
  <div >
    {this.state.titles.map(this.eachTitle)}

    {this.state.recipes.map(this.eachRecipe)}


  </div>
      </div>
  );
}
});


ReactDOM.render(<Board />
, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Basically its a recipe title followed by a recipe. The problem is once I render a few what happens is that all the titles go together and not with each recipe eg...
I want it like this..

```
Chicken Reicpe
Recipe here

Beef Recipe
Recipe Here

Cococnut Recipe
Recipe here

Instead its like this.

Chicken Recipe
Beef Recipe
Coconut Recipe

Recipe
Recipe
Recipe
```

How can I render them together? If you need more code or clarification let me know. Any suggestions to improve code? If it's too long to read let me know too. 
Thanks,

Comment: you want to render the same recipes for all recipeTiles ? can you show the array and more code of those two functions ?

Comment: Why do you have your data separated anyway? It would be much cleaner to keep the titles with the recipes, since a title is part of the overall recipe. Instead of mucking around with your dual-array structure, fix your data, and have a `<Recipe />` component that renders the title and recipe.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I will try that later

Comment: How can you add then a recipe and title to the one array as a state? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your data look like. So I suppose the two states data will look like this

```
repTitles: [{
        text: 'chicken'
    }, {
        text: 'beef'
    }],
repFormulars: [{
        text: 'chicken-rep'
    }, {
        text: 'beef-rep'
    }]
```

Then in your render function, you can simply loop through it like

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.repTitles.map((title, idx) => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <p>{title.text}</p>
                        <p>{this.state.repFormulars[idx].text}</p>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

It's straightforward so you can get the idea easily. You could add className to the `<p>` tag, in case you want to customize it using stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reconcile the two lists. Suppose `recipeTiles` has a property of `recipe_id` and `recipe` has a property of `id`. You can simply do something like this:

```
renderRecipes() {
  const { recipes, recipeTiles } = this.props;
  recipes.map(recipe => {
    const tile = recipeTiles.find(({ recipe_id }) => recipe_id === recipe.id);
    return (
      <div>
        <RecipeTile {...tile} />
        <Recipe {...recipe} />
      </div>
    );
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a old fashioned loop. Instead of this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.recipeTiles.map(this.eachTitle)}
      {this.state.recipes.map(this.eachRecipe)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You could e.g. do this:

```
render() {
  const result = [];
  const { recipeTiles, recipes } = this.state;
  for(let i = 0; i < recipeTiles.length; i++) {
    result.push(this.eachTitle(recipeTiles[i]));
    result.push(this.eachRecipe(recipes[i]));
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {result}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to associate each recipe with a recipe title and then render them together. Your render method should sort of look like this:

```js
render(){

  // This gives us a container that has recipe and title properties
  const recipeContainers = this.state.recipes.map( (recipe, index) => {
    const title = this.state.recipeTiles[index]
    return {
      title,
      recipe
    }
  })

  // Now that we have the info bundled together, we can spit it out on the page
  return (
    <div>
      {recipeContainers.map( ({recipe, title}) => (
      <dl>
        <dt>{this.eachTitle(title)}</dt>
        <dd>{this.eachRecipe(recipe)}</dt>
      </dl>
      )
    </div>
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just access the recipes from recipe array by the index, when iterating through the recipe array

```
render(){
    var recipe = [...this.state.recipe];
    return(
       <div>
           {this.state.recipeTiles.map((title, index) => {
                   return (
                          <div key={index}>
                               <div>{title}</div>
                               <div>{recipe[index]}</div>
                          </div>

                   )
            });
       </div>
    )
}
```