# ReactJS - How do I render out a component from several prop arrays?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, components

I am trying to learn ReactJS by building a simple web application that makes several ajax calls to a mock api and rendering the results onto the page.

So far, I can successfully make an ajax call to the mock api via the appropriate use of componentDidMount. The response text is a JSON object, where I store several arrays in state, for example:

```
var newTitle = this.state.title.slice();
newTitle.push(myObject[x].title);
this.setState({title:newTitle})

var newBody = this.state.body.slice();
newBody.push(myObject[x].body);
this.setState({body:newBody})
```

myObject is the object storing the parsed JSON response.

I can successfully render out one array (i.e. title) by doing the following:

```
<FeedController title={this.state.title}/>

class FeedController extends Component{
  render({
    return(
      {this.props.title.map(function(element,i){
        return <FeedItem title={element} />
      })}
    );
  });
}

class FeedItem extends Component{
  render({
    return(
      <div>
      Title: {this.props.title}
      </div>
    );
  });
```

I loop through the title state and display a FeedItem with each iteration. My problem and question, however, is how do I render out a component from several prop arrays? For example, I would like title[1] to be displayed alongside body[1] etc.

I presume I would do something where I pass title and body as props, but I can't work out how to map both and also render out the results. Ideally, my FeedItem component will look like the following:

```
class FeedItem extends Component{
  render({
    return(
      <div>
      Title: {this.props.title}
      <br />
      Body: {this.props.body}
      <br /><br />
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: This is a very similar question to one I've seen before. Check out the question and the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070866/react-rendering-multiple-components/44071131#44071131

Comment: ^ 2nd. What you really need to think about is how to merge the multiple arrays into one dataset. Then you can use the same logic as you mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the arrays will be the same length, you can use the same index to get matching data.

```
<FeedController title={this.state.title} body={this.state.body}/>

class FeedController extends Component{
  render({
    return(
      {this.props.title.map(function(element,i){
        return <FeedItem title={element} body={this.props.body[i]} />
      })}
    );
  });
}

class FeedItem extends Component{
  render({
    return(
      <div>
      Title: {this.props.title}
      <br />
      Body: {this.props.body}
      <br /><br />
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Alternatively, you can merge the data before you pass it in to the FeedController.

```
render(){
    let data = this.state.title.map( (title, i) => {
        return {
            title: title,
            body: this.state.body[i]
        }
    }
    return <FeedController data={data} />
}

class FeedController extends Component{
  render({
    return(
      {this.props.data.map( (data,i) => {
        return <FeedItem title={data.title} body={data.body} />
      })}
    );
  });
}

class FeedItem extends Component{
  render({
    return(
      <div>
      Title: {this.props.title}
      <br />
      Body: {this.props.body}
      <br /><br />
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: I have tried the first approach so far, and I am still struggling. I cannot create a prop with an existing prop/state within the FeedController, i.e. return <FeedItem title={title} body={this.props.body[index]}/> doesn't work. The error I am getting is "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined"

Comment: Ah, that's because you need to use a fat arrow function or bind your map function to this `.map( (a,b) => {})` or `.map(function(a,b,){}).bind(this)`